# How to convert the datetime field in Django to be accepted by google calendar event?

Tags: python-3.x, django, google-calendar-api

I have a model contains start, end field with like this

```
def get_deadline():
        return datetime.today() + timedelta(days=0, hours=0,minutes=40)
    
 class Schedule(models.Model):
         start = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=False)
         end = models.DateTimeField(default=get_deadline, blank=False)
```

When I print out is show

```
start = 2020-07-08 17:42:00

end =2020-07-08 18:22:43.588789
```

How can I convert the `start` and `end` to date accepted by googel calendar event, this accepted format is look like this:

```
date_calendar_event = 2020-07-08 10:53:32.725308+00:00
```

Comment: You can use `start.isoformat()` to print it in a ISO 8601 style.

Comment: Then you can just append "+00:00" like `start.isoformat() + "+00:00"`

Answer (score 1):

This function returns the desired:

```
import datetime
def to_local_time(date, time):
   date=date.split('-')
   time=time.split(':')
   if 'AM' in time[1] or 'PM' in time[1]: time[1]=time[1][:2]
   dt = datetime.datetime(int(date[0]), int(date[1]), int(date[2])
   ,int(time[0]), int(time[1]), 00).astimezone().isoformat()
   return dt

print(to_local_time('2023-03-15','10:00AM'))
```